# How to return variable result if csv file is not exist

Tags: java

I would like to know that how to do if my csv file is not exist and has been renamed or moved to other location then the return value should pass to other variable so that I will call that variable to read in other method.

Here is my code -

```
  public static String getSites() {
    // .csv comma separated values
    String csvFile = "C:\\SWAPIData/riglist.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String sites = "'";

    try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line != "")
          sites = sites + line + "','";
        else
          continue;
      }

      if (sites != null && sites.length() > 1)
        sites = sites.substring(0, sites.length() - 2);
      else
        return "";

      //System.out.println(sites);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (br != null) {
        try {
          br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return sites;
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the given code? Is there something not working?

Comment: The code is working fine, but I want to know if the location of ("C:\\SWAPIData/riglist.csv") as given in code is changed due to some circumstances, then it should return blank, and that blank query I will call in my other method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `try` block, first check if the file exists. If doesn't, then return empty string.

```
if (!new File(csvFile).exists()) {
    return "";
}
```

You can also use [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to check if the file exists

```
if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(csvFile))) {
    return "";
}
```